# NOT EXISTS not considered in the results

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get the results from 'comments' table with the exception of the ones in the `'readsbaby'` table.
The result i'm getting is from comments but no effect of the `NOT EXISTS` statement, so the result is all the comments.

Both tables have common data that should not be included in the result.
I checked the data and the syntax many times.
Still this query will return all comments without taking in consideration the `AND NOT EXISTS` close.

```
public function get_user_comments($post_id)
{

$user_id = $this->session->userdata('id');
$group_id = $this->session->userdata('group_id');

  $sql = "SELECT * 
    FROM comments  
    WHERE DATE(created_on) > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
    AND comments.group_id = " . $group_id . " 
    AND comments.user_id != " . $user_id . "  
        AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
               FROM readsbaby
               WHERE comments.id = readsbaby.notification_id 
               AND comments.group_id = readsbaby.group_id  
               AND readsbaby.user_id = " . $this->session->userdata('id') . " 
               AND comments.nature1 = readsbaby.notification_type 
             )    ";

    return $data=$this->db->query($sql)->result_array();

}
```

Expecting to get the result filtered by the `NOT EXISTS` close.

Comment: What is `$this->session->userdata('id')` ? Shouldn't it be `... AND readsbaby.user_id = comments.user_id` ?

Comment: @GMB they are equal, using comments.user_id  have same effect.

Comment: Echo your request and execute it directly on your DB (without PHP). Does it give the expected result?

Comment: @Jeto I did that and get the same result. No consideration for the NOT EXISTS.

Comment: Run the `NOT EXIST` clause separately and see what comes out. Are you sure that you are not seeing records that should not be there ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd change the query this way, to have only the rows without any match in the table readsbaby:

```
public function get_user_comments($post_id)
{

$user_id = $this->session->userdata('id');
$group_id = $this->session->userdata('group_id');

  $sql = "SELECT * 
    FROM comments 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  readsbaby ON comments.id = readsbaby.notification_id 
               AND comments.group_id = readsbaby.group_id  
               AND readsbaby.user_id = " . $this->session->userdata('id') . " 
               AND comments.nature1 = readsbaby.notification_type

    WHERE DATE(created_on) > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
    AND comments.group_id = " . $group_id . " 
    AND comments.user_id != " . $user_id . "  
    AND ISNULL(readsbaby.notification_id )";

    return $data=$this->db->query($sql)->result_array();

}
```

Comment: Got same result as my query :(

Comment: What result are you getting? Could you post the format of your tables?

Answer (score 0):

This is easier to accomplish using the correct mysql `JOIN`.

From your post, I have gathered that you want to retrieve all the values from `comments` where they don't exist in `readsbaby`.  The `id` column in `comments` associates with the `notification_id` in `readsbaby` for any 'matching' (duplicate) entries.

On this assumption, you can do this at a simplistic level like so

```
SELECT c.* FROM comments c
LEFT JOIN readsbaby r ON c.id = r.id WHERE r.notification_id IS NULL;
```

...which should translate to your context as something like:

```
SELECT c.* FROM comments c  
 LEFT JOIN readsbaby r ON c.id = r.notification_id   
WHERE
  r.notification_id IS NULL 
  AND DATE(c.created_on) > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
  AND c.group_id = " . $group_id . " 
  AND c.user_id != " . $user_id . "
```

---

If, I have this wrong and you're **looking to only get the data that isn't present in both**, you'd need to use something like:

```
SELECT c.* FROM comments c  
 LEFT JOIN readsbaby r ON c.id = r.notification_id   
WHERE
  r.notification_id IS NULL 
  AND DATE(c.created_on) > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
  AND c.group_id = " . $group_id . " 
  AND c.user_id != " . $user_id . " 
UNION
SELECT r.* FROM readsbaby r  
 LEFT JOIN comments c ON c.id = r.notification_id   
WHERE
  c.id IS NULL  
  AND r.group_id = " . $group_id . " 
  AND r.user_id != " . $user_id . "
```

This may need tweaking to suit, as there's very little to explain the data and table relationship.

**Note:** Do not inject SQL as you've done.  Consider parameterising your query with PDO or any other prepared statements (e.g. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)